# No method error using ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar after update to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

after update my app to Rails 5 i am struggling with the following error.
I will post a snippet of my rspec test code.

This is my cookies method.

```
 def cookies
    request = page.driver.request

    ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.build(request, request.cookies).tap do |jar|
      jar.update(
        page.driver.browser.rack_mock_session.cookie_jar.to_hash
      )
    end
  end
```

When i try to call cookies.signed

```
(byebug) cookies.signed
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `secret_token' for #<Rack::Request:0x007fd9702b3710>
```

Printscreen of the test error

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you run your tests with `-b` flag to enable the full backtrace, and then show us at least 10 lines of the top of the backlog?

Comment: Failures:

  1) Showroom / Invites Setting the cookies when visiting the join page only sets the referral_code cookie when visiting the general join page
     Failure/Error: expect(cookies.signed["guesstimated_user_type"]).to be nil

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `secret_token' for #<Rack::Request:0x007fa418df1ad8>
     # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:241:in `upgrade_legacy_signed_cookies?'
     # ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:197:in `signed'

Comment: From which Rails version you are upgrading? Do you have the secrets.yml setup in your app? ([see here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml))

Comment: 4.2 , yes i have it!

Comment: And on your secrets.yml you have the key `test:` ?

Comment: yes, with secret_key_base

Comment: Did you run `rake secret` and it worked fine?

Comment: yeap, it generates the secret with no problem

Comment: Might this be helpful? https://sikac.hu/reconstruct-a-cookie-jar-and-read-signed-cookie-in-capybara-f71df387f9ff#.nqsa2cwxe